# Custom view action in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I created a custom `View` because different `UIViewController` are having identical appearance.

[image]

It appeared to be a whole blank when I add the custom `View` into `UIViewController`. That doesn't matter. What matter is how do I create an `action` for the invisible `Button` overlay on the `ImageView`? I cannot seem to connect `Sent Action` of the invisible `Button` to my `UIViewController`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
@Mannopson this is how I did

```
import UIKit

class BookDetailsView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var wholeView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var borderView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgBook: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtTitle: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtAuthor: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtDesc: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnUploadPhoto: UIButton!

    //init for custom draw
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        customInit()
    }

    //init for ib
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        customInit()
//        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func customInit(){
        //load xib
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("BookDetailsView", owner: self, options: nil)

        //add wholeView as subView
        addSubview(wholeView)

        //auto fit
        wholeView.frame = self.bounds
        wholeView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        borderView.layer.borderWidth = 3
        borderView.layer.cornerRadius = 40
    }

}
```

Comment: It's a XIB file right?

Comment: @Mannopson yes, then I attach it to a View class

Comment: Can you show me some codes ? How to attach it to the `viewController` ?

Comment: @Mannopson hi added

Comment: In this case you'll need outlets only and not anything else. You can use the .XIB files just portion of view. Therefore you should try to load this view in `UIViewController` not inside of `UIView` Subclass. And you'll get a whole control of this custom view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essence, assigning an action to `UIImageView` is a bad practice. You don't have to use image view to handle tap (even though technically you can). Instead, use simple UIButton, remove its text, border and its color, and simply set an image to it. You will get just what you want, without unnecessary overlays and such stuff. It's easier and is appropriate.

---

**Edit** (extract from comments which reveal another issue):

To add custom view to the view hierarchy. Most typical way:

Create a subclass of `UIViewController` with that class owning all the outlets. Then create a separate storyboard file (or you can even use current). Then simply instantiate it programmatically and by doing that, access the `view` property. Add that `view` as a subview to the view hierarchy of currently shown `UIViewController`.

Other solutions include:

1) Use container view to manage nested `UIViewController`.

2) Use separate `XIB` file for your custom view and instantiate it programmatically.

Comment: Either way, the custom View works as a whole in UIViewController. I'm looking for a way to drag the invisible UIButton out onto my UIViewController which doesn't work.

Comment: What is the issue are you experiencing with dragging? You can easily move objects in IB, directly or by using object hierarchy view. And lastly, why did you have to make button invisible? You can move it within the hierarchy view and manually set coordinates or layout constraints to reposition it.

Comment: Dragging is easy from IB to a View class. But I was dragging from the View class to my UIViewController. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I believe you are. `UIViewController` is a controller, it's a `C` in `MVC` pattern which means that by itself it has nothing to do with the View. However it does manage the View. In iOS, `UIViewController` and `View` is a tightly coupled pair. UIViewController should have a view it manages. And if you want your other views (like buttons, labels) to relate to that Controller, you place them onto a `View` managed by that `UIViewController`.

Comment: Yes your statement is so close to what I want. How do I inform the UIViewController to manage the View?

Comment: I did put the view into a UIViewController, but I cannot drag any connection from the View onto UIViewController

Comment: There are several ways, depending on the situation. The easiest and most typical way: you create a subclass of UIViewController with that class owning all the outlets. Then create a XIB or a separate storyboard file (or you can even use current). Then you can simply instantiate it programmatically and by doing that, access the `view` property. Add that `view` as a subview to the view hierarchy of currently shown UIViewController.

Comment: Other solutions include: 1) use container view. 2) Use separate XIB file for your custom view. One of these options let you include your view directly into IB.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
class BookDetailsView: UIView {

@IBOutlet var wholeView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var borderView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var imgBook: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var txtTitle: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtAuthor: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtDesc: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var btnUploadPhoto: UIButton!

}
```

Load the custom view in `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method:

```
let customView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("YourXIBName", owner: self, options: nil).first as! YourUIViewSubclass

// Customize appearence
customView.btnUploadPhoto.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

// Add an action for this button
customView.btnUploadPhoto.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourFunctionForUIButton), forControlEvents: .touchUpInside)

self.view.addSubview(customView)
```

A custom function:

```
func yourFunctionForUIButton() { 
}
```

Hope it helps. This not not an answer for your main question and it's just recommendation

Answer (score 2):

The possible reasons for being unable to connect an Outlet are:

- The ViewController (in InterfaceBuilder) hasn't been attached to it's ViewController class i.e. no custom class has been specified in the Identity Inspector
- The wrong action/outlet pair i.e. trying to connect a button action to a view

Comment: so I create UIViewController for the custom View, and attach the whole custom UIViewController to my interface instead of just View?

Comment: No, did you check if the custom class of the UIViewController has been set to your class for it?

Comment: The custom class is subclass of UIView, not UIViewController. Is there any reference about proper way to create custom view?

Comment: Now I follow. You are trying to connect the button of UIView to an outlet in UIViewController.
You don't need to add a custom view. Simply copy all your code, except the init, into the view controller class. Connect the outlets. You should be good to go.

Comment: How do I use the UIViewController in Storyboard? It works if I programmatically instantiate it, but I want to put it in storyboard instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should add gesture to your ImageView.

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

Comment: Please read the question careful. He did specify there's an invisible button which he's trying to connect to the action.